# Test framework quits unexpectedly - IntelliJ python plugin

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, intellij-idea, python-unittest

I'm having a big problem with the testing framework in IntelliJ using with the python plugin.
When I launch my tests, written using `unittest`, the tests fail with an import error in the `_jb_test_runner` file.
I surfed the net for a while, but didn't get a useful solution. See the stacktrace below:

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/davide/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/config/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py --path /home/davide/Scrivania/musical-store/test/types/test_person.py
Testing started at 12.35 ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/davide/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/config/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py", line 4, in <module>
    from unittest import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from .result import TestResult
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/result.py", line 5, in <module>
    import traceback
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/linecache.py", line 8, in <module>
    import functools
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/functools.py", line 22, in <module>
    from types import MappingProxyType
ImportError: cannot import name 'MappingProxyType'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 62, in apport_excepthook
    import re, traceback
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/linecache.py", line 8, in <module>
    import functools
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/functools.py", line 22, in <module>
    from types import MappingProxyType
ImportError: cannot import name 'MappingProxyType'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/davide/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/config/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py", line 4, in <module>
    from unittest import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from .result import TestResult
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/result.py", line 5, in <module>
    import traceback
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/linecache.py", line 8, in <module>
    import functools
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/functools.py", line 22, in <module>
    from types import MappingProxyType
ImportError: cannot import name 'MappingProxyType'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The code does not present any syntax error, but the problem started after a refactoring of the whole project I'm working on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a file called `types.py`?

Comment: It's a package, not a file

Comment: Yeah, its conflicting with the built-in `types` which is the source of your error.

Comment: You were right, renaming the package worked. Thanks a lot man!